# How to remove information within parenthesis in python, regex or otherwise?

Tags: python, regex, csv

I've been reading into regex but I'm still not really understanding how it integrates into Python.  I have a dictionary of movie names drawn from a csv file in the format (as you can see, the formatting is odd, with words like "The" coming after the main title and the movie year occurring in parenthesis after the movie title):

```
3582,"Jails, Hospitals & Hip-Hop (2000)",Comedy|Documentary|Drama
3583,Black Tights (1-2-3-4 ou Les Collants noirs) (1960),Drama|Musical
3584,Breathless (1983),Action|Drama|Romance|Thriller
3585,"Great Locomotive Chase, The (1956)",Adventure|War
3586,The Idolmaker (1980),Drama|Romance
3587,Inferno (1980),Horror
```

The dictionary is in the following format (this is a printout of dict.items()), where the key is the movie name and the values are the movie genres (either one or multiple) in a list:

```
[('Little Big League (1994)', ['Comedy', 'Drama']), ('Alex in Wonderland (1970)', ['Comedy', 'Drama']), ('3 Braves (2015)', ['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children']), ('Where Are My Children? (1916)', ['Drama']), ('Panic Room (2002)', ['Thriller']), ('Girls, Les (1957)', ['Musical']), ('Family, The (2013)', ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Crime']), ('Le bal des casse-pieds (1992)', ['Comedy']), ('Legend of Suram Fortress, The (Ambavi Suramis tsikhitsa) (1986) ', ['Drama']), ('Blades of Blood (2010)', ['Action', 'Drama']), ("Where's Marlowe? (1998)", ['Comedy']), ('Passenger Side (2009)', ['Comedy', 'Drama'])...etc...]
```

I want to strip any information from the information in column [1], so I can use the dictionary to find genres for an unrelated list of a few hundred movies.  The problem is, these movies contain the year and odd formatting ("The" is after the rest of the title), making it difficult to do a "==" comparison to find a movie in the dictionary.

GOAL:  I want to iterate through my list of movies, find them in the dictionary keys, and print a line in a csv file containing the movie name with it's genres.

QUESTION:  How can I scrape away the space and year afterwards the movie?

METHODS:  2 ways... 1) Import the movies from the csv file into the dictionary, scraping the year from the title, or 2) check if my movie title from the unrelated list is a substring of the string movie in the dictionary keys, negating the need to actually remove the year (i.e. (1999)) in the first place.

Thanks for the help, I am still learning.

Comment: Post your dictionary. The content of the code block is imcomplete python

Comment: Dictionary posted.

Comment: `[('Little Big League (1994)', ['Comedy', 'Drama']), ('Alex in Wonderland (1970)', ['Comedy', 'Drama'])...]` That is not a dict; it is a list.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly I think you the following code:

```
In [22]: d
Out[22]: 
{3582: 'Jails, Hospitals & Hip-Hop (2000)',
 3583: 'Black Tights (1-2-3-4 ou Les Collants noirs) (1960)',
 3584: 'Breathless (1983)'}

In [23]: for id, movie in d.iteritems():
    print id, re.sub('\(.*\)', '', movie)
   ....:     
3584 Breathless 
3582 Jails, Hospitals & Hip-Hop 
3583 Black Tights 

In [24]:
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression (using named groups):

```
(?<id>\d{1,10}),("|)(?<description>.{0,200})("|),(?<tags>.{1,100})
```

[Check the results here.](http://rubular.com/r/JiYY1e7pUG)

Comment: This is regular expressions, if you need any doubt, please, refer to this web-site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `re` module to do regular expressions

```
import re
```

All of your `movies` are nicely grouped as tuples stored in a list, so you can iterate over the movies and grab the `name` and `list of genres` into variables

```
movies = [('Little Big League (1994)', ['Comedy', 'Drama']),
          ('Alex in Wonderland (1970)', ['Comedy', 'Drama']),
          ('3 Braves (2015)', ['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children']),
          ('Where Are My Children? (1916)', ['Drama']),
          ('Panic Room (2002)', ['Thriller']),
          ('Girls, Les (1957)', ['Musical']),
          ('Family, The (2013)', ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Crime']),
          ('Le bal des casse-pieds (1992)', ['Comedy']),
          ('Legend of Suram Fortress, The (Ambavi Suramis tsikhitsa) (1986) ', ['Drama']),
          ('Blades of Blood (2010)', ['Action', 'Drama']),
          ("Where's Marlowe? (1998)", ['Comedy']),
          ('Passenger Side (2009)', ['Comedy', 'Drama'])]

for movie in movies:
    name, genres = movie
```

if you want to remove the year from the movie title, you can use the following regular expression:

```
'[(][0-9]*[)]'
```

`[(]` means match an opening bracket

`[0-9]*` means match any amount of numbers

`[)]` means match a closing bracket

You can then use the re module to substitute anything that matches this regular expression with an empty string, removing it from the variable

```
    print('Movie Name: {0}'.format(re.sub('[(][0-9]*[)]', '', name)))
    print('Genres: {0}\n'.format(', '.join(genres)))
```

Lets put it all together:

```
import re

movies = [('Little Big League (1994)', ['Comedy', 'Drama']),
          ('Alex in Wonderland (1970)', ['Comedy', 'Drama']),
          ('3 Braves (2015)', ['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children']),
          ('Where Are My Children? (1916)', ['Drama']),
          ('Panic Room (2002)', ['Thriller']),
          ('Girls, Les (1957)', ['Musical']),
          ('Family, The (2013)', ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Crime']),
          ('Le bal des casse-pieds (1992)', ['Comedy']),
          ('Legend of Suram Fortress, The (Ambavi Suramis tsikhitsa) (1986) ', ['Drama']),
          ('Blades of Blood (2010)', ['Action', 'Drama']),
          ("Where's Marlowe? (1998)", ['Comedy']),
          ('Passenger Side (2009)', ['Comedy', 'Drama'])]

for movie in movies:
    name, genres = movie
    print('Movie Name: {0}'.format(re.sub('[(][0-9]*[)]', '', name)))
    print('Genres: {0}\n'.format(', '.join(genres)))
```

Output:

```
Movie Name: Little Big League 
Genres: Comedy, Drama

Movie Name: Alex in Wonderland 
Genres: Comedy, Drama

Movie Name: 3 Braves 
Genres: Adventure, Animation, Children

Movie Name: Where Are My Children? 
Genres: Drama

Movie Name: Panic Room 
Genres: Thriller

Movie Name: Girls, Les 
Genres: Musical

Movie Name: Family, The 
Genres: Action, Comedy, Crime

Movie Name: Le bal des casse-pieds 
Genres: Comedy

Movie Name: Legend of Suram Fortress, The (Ambavi Suramis tsikhitsa)  
Genres: Drama

Movie Name: Blades of Blood 
Genres: Action, Drama

Movie Name: Where's Marlowe? 
Genres: Comedy

Movie Name: Passenger Side 
Genres: Comedy, Drama


Process finished with exit code 0
```